# If statement executes the else statement

Tags: java

I am making a number guessing game in where it generates a random number and the user has to guess it. I am asking the user to try again but if they say yes it gives the else statement and if they say no it works as planned.

> I wanted to mention that the number guessing part does also not work. What I mean is that it is for some reason not letting the user ever guess the number right. It doesn't give me any error so I do not know what to do.  so please help me out with that too if you can. Also, I am very new to Java so if there is an obvious solution please do not make fun of me.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      while (true){
System.out.print("Guess a number 1-10.");
Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(10);
Scanner numgood = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = numgood.next();
if (a.equals(n)) {
  System.out.println("Correct! Wanna do another round? (yes/no)\n"); 
  Scanner round  = new Scanner(System.in);
  String r = round.next();
  if (r.equals("yes")) {
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
  System.out.flush();  
  }
  if (r.equals("no")) {
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing! Bye!");
    System.exit(0);
    numgood.close();
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Answer with a correct statement");
    round.close();
  }
}
else {
  System.out.println("Incorrect! Wanna do another round?\n");
    Scanner round2  = new Scanner(System.in);
    String e = round2.next();
  if (e.equals("yes")) {
    System.out.flush();
  }
  if (e.equals("no")) {
    System.out.flush();
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing! Bye!");
    System.exit(0);
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Answer with a correct statement");
    round2.close();
  }
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: "does also not work" is very vague: please provide more details

Comment: Your `else` belongs to the `if (r.equals("no"))`, so it will always be executed when the user does not enter "no". What you want to do is use the `if ... else if ... else` syntax. So change the `if (r.equals("no"))` to `else if (r.equals("no"))`

Comment: Hey @SamiOsman21 and welcome to Stackoverflow! If you want a good answer, please try to format your code so that it becomes more readable. Also, please specify, what you mean by 'does not work'.

Comment: @kroegerama I just updated the question. Go check it out!

Comment: convert `n` to String with `String.valueOf(n)`. or convert `a` to integer using `Integer.valueOf(a)`

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` method at first checks if the given parameter is the same *type* as the object, this method is called on.

You declare variable `n` as an `int` and variable `a` as a `String` The `equals` method as implemented in class `String` returns `false` because `n` is *not* of type `String`.

---

> In that case, how would I fix it? – SamiOsman21

At your level you should change `a` to type `int` too and compare it with `n` using the `==` operator. Of cause you also have to change `a = numgood.next();` to `a = numgood.nextInt();`.

Comment: In that case, how would I fix it?

Comment: @SamiOsman21 please see the updated answer